# SPFx webpart icons

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts, icons

Trying to use external `.png` icon for my web-part but the don't appear both on local workbench as well as on production SharePoint online.

I have uploaded on Office 365 public CDN. **All my icon size is 512px x 512px**.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx/client-side-web-part-manifest.schema.json",
  "id": "5da88f8a-0ead-4664-ae07-c81c78b5ebdf",
  "alias": "HomePageCarouselWebPart",
  "componentType": "WebPart",
  // The "*" signifies that the version should be taken from the package.json
  "version": "*",
  "manifestVersion": 2,
  // If true, the component can only be installed on sites where Custom Script is allowed.
  // Components that allow authors to embed arbitrary script code should set this to true.
  // https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f
  "requiresCustomScript": false,
  "supportedHosts": [
    "SharePointWebPart"
  ],
  "preconfiguredEntries": [
    {
      "groupId": "5c03119e-3074-46fd-976b-c60198311f70", // Other
      "group": {
        "default": "Other"
      },
      "title": {
        "default": "Home Page Carousel"
      },
      "description": {
        "default": "Home Page Carousel description"
      },
      "iconImageUrl": "https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/DeveloperSite/CdnPublic/web-parts-icon/slider.png",
      "properties": {
        "description": "Home Page Carousel"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I directly try to access icon it gives me access denied.

[image]

Guide me how to get icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **base64-encoded image** as recommended in below documentation:

> When using a custom image, rather than specifying an absolute URL to the image file hosted together with other web part assets, you can have your image base64-encoded and use the base64 string instead of the URL.
>
> A number of services are available online that you can use to base64-encode your image; for more information, see [Convert your images to Base64](https://www.base64-image.de/).

**Source**: [Configure web part icon - Use a base64-encoded image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/configure-web-part-icon#use-a-base64-encoded-image).

**Steps to Use**:

1. Encode the image.
2. Copy the base64 string and use it as the value for the **iconImageUrl** property in the web part manifest.

**Example**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://dev.office.com/json-schemas/spfx/client-side-web-part-manifest.schema.json",
  "id": "bcae7077-85cb-41a0-b3d3-2084f268a211",
  "alias": "WeatherWebPart",
  "componentType": "WebPart",
  // The "*" signifies that the version should be taken from the package.json
  "version": "*",
  "manifestVersion": 2,
  // If true, the component can only be installed on sites where Custom Script is allowed.
  // Components that allow authors to embed arbitrary script code should set this to true.
  // https://support.office.com/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f
  "requiresCustomScript": false,
  "preconfiguredEntries": [
    {
      "groupId": "5c03119e-3074-46fd-976b-c60198311f70", // Other
      "group": {
        "default": "Other"
      },
      "title": {
        "default": "Weather"
      },
      "description": {
        "default": "Shows current weather in the given location"
      },
      "iconImageUrl": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTAyMiIgaGVpZ2h0PSI5NzgiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6c3ZnPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+CiA8Zz4KICA8dGl0bGU+TGF5ZXIgMTwvdGl...",
      "properties": {
        "location": "Munich"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> **Note**:
> Base64 encoding works for both bitmap images, such as PNG, as well as vector SVG images. The big benefit of using base64-encoded images is that you don't need to deploy the web part icon image separately.

Comment: That's works the trick. Thank you for guidance